# Laravel 5.7 How to get data from Controller show($id) function? Used Query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`StaffController`

```
public function show($id){
  $staffinfo = DB::table('staff')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
  return view('staff.view')->with('staffinfo', $staffinfo); 
}
```

`view.blade.php`

```
<h1>{{$staffinfo->name}}</h1>
<p>{{$staffinfo->user_id}}</p>
```

Is this code right to show data from staff table in view by `show($id)` function?

Getting error:

> "Property [name] does not exist on this collection
>   instance. (View:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\gchsc\resources\views\staff\view.blade.php)"

Answer (score 2):

Switch `->get()` to `->first()`. `$staffInfo` is a `Collection` of database records, not a single one:

`StaffController.php`

```
$staffinfo = DB::table('staff')->where('user_id', $id)->first();
```

Then the following will work in your view:

`staff/view.blade.php`

```
<h1>{{ $staffinfo->name }}</h1>
<p>{{ $staffinfo->user_id }}</p>
```

Or, leave your code as is and iterate in your view:

`StaffController.php`

```
$staffinfo = DB::table('staff')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

`staff/view.blade.php`

```
@foreach($staffInfo AS $staff){
  <h1>{{ $staff->name }}</h1>
  <p>{{ $staff->user_id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped, please consider up voting and/or accept it.